# Hausdorff and Closed Set equivalence

Tags: general-topology

This is a question I've been stuck on for a half hour, and I fear there is some elementary trick I may be missing. I have done the "commonly seen" direction, and cannot do the other:

Let $Y$ topological space. Show that $Y$ is Hausdorff iff for all topological spaces $X$, and pairs of continuous maps $f$,$g$ $:X \to Y$, the set {${x \in X : f(x) = g(x)}$} is closed.

I have shown that $Y$ Hausdorff implies that our set is closed easily. The other direction eludes me. Can anyone write maybe the first two-three lines of a successful solution? This is embarrassing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your hypothesis to the canonical projections $\pi_1,\pi_2:Y\times Y \longrightarrow Y$.

This implies that the set $\Delta=\lbrace (y,y)\in Y\times Y\rbrace$ is closed, and then you can use the fact that $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\Delta$ is closed.

Comment: Did you see my answer...?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Oh, my bad, I thought that your answer was by contradiction.

Comment: Bingo. I literally just thought of this myself.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I must have seen an older version of your answer, now I see what you mean.

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz I edited it two minutes ago. Maybe you didn't see it. +1 for a thought sharing.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks, and I sincerely apologize for not being mindful of the edit.

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz Nevermind, it seems I edited just when you posted.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint* Can you find a suitable space $X$ and suitable functions for which $\{x\in X:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is $\{(y,y):y\in Y\}$?